# How would I use AWS to send quick payloads to my iOS app when data is changed in a DynamoDB table?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need an efficient way of sending payloads to my iOS app when a database change occurs.

Specifically, if a user's location is updated their client app will invoke a Lambda function that updates their location, stored in a DyanmoDB Table. When this occurs I need a way to then invoke some code and send a payload to other users, depending on some conditions. I think Lambda would be used for this but I'm not sure, does that sound correct? How would I go about implementing this in lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To invoke some code when a DynamoDB table is updated you would use Lambda. I would look at [this documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html), and possibly [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-update-triggers-streams-lambda-cross-region-replication-app/).

To send a payload to your iOS app, I believe you would want to configure an SNS topic to send Apple Push Notification messages. The documentation for this is [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-apns.html).

To add a message to the SNS topic via your Lambda function you would use standard AWS SDK code to create an SNS message.